# Lazarus (Free Pascal). Seemingly unnecessary compiler warning

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I'm new to Free Pascal and Lazarus. I'm testing out the new "advanced records" feature and getting what looks to be an unnecessary compiler warning.

The code is very simple, just a record with a single method to initialize the data fields. Something like:

```
{$mode delphi}

type TTest =
  record
    a,b: double;
    procedure Init(x,y: double);
  end

procedure TTest.Init(x,y: double);
begin
  test.a := x;
  test.b := y;
end;


var t: TTest;
begin
  t.Init(0.1,0.2);
```

That last line shown, "t.Init()", always generates a compiler warning that '**variable "t" does not seem to have been initialized**'.

Ok it's only warning, so obviously I can live with it, but I just want to make sure it's not due to some underlying misunderstanding on my part.

---

**EDIT to add new information.**

Re the Method verus Constructor point.
Looking into this some more I'm kind of glad that FPC doesn't allow constructors for records. Delphi has constructors but no destructors, and as far as I can tell constructors (for records) do absolutely nothing that a method couldn't do. I'm a minimalist, so to me there is no point to have extra syntax that does nothing more than some existing syntax does.

Particularly for a simple record like this, the very act of declaring it (**var t: TTest**) does all the "constructing" that this record needs. Anything else (like my Init) is just setting values, it's not constructing anything anyway. So as far as I can see constructors are not the answer, the compiler just needs to drop the warning.

Researching the issue I have come across one other technique that is often used, the so called "factory function". That is, a function **outside** of the record such as:

```
function InitTTest(x,y: double): TTest;
begin
  Result.a := x;
  Result.b := y;
end;
```

This technique does indeed work, and gets rid of the warning message. I don't like this method however and I wont use it. Advanced records don't have inheritance and other features of classes, encapsulation is all they've got going for them. So I really dislike having to make a "factory function" outside of the record like this.

Please bear in mind the the above is just the opinion of a "noob", after doing just a little research to answer my own question here. So if I'm wrong about anything above I'm quite happy to be corrected. :)

Comment: Well technically, the warning *is* correct - you *are* using `t` without it having been initialized. The compiler doesn't know that you are going to be using the `Init` method to set up the record (I suppose it could figure it out, but it looks like a lot of work for more complex records). I guess this is what constructors are for, but I'm a bit rusty on FreePascal so I'm not sure if records can have constructors (in the technical sense).

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Yes I always use constructors when using classes but not for records since they aren't dynamically "instantiated" like classes. But you're right, these new records can have constructors, so I'll try that and report back.

Comment: Just updating my finds re using a constructor. Apparently Delphi allows records to have constructors but not FPC. I just tested changing Init() from a procedure to a constructor and it gives the message "**Error: Constructors aren't allowed in records or record helpers.**". So I guess that's not the answer.

Comment: Another update: I was able to test this on Delphi (D2009) and the code works correctly and issues no warnings. Additionally, D2009 does allow this "setter" to be defined as either a **procedure** or a **constructor**, though it operates exactly the same either way. It appears that FPC doesn't allow constructors for records (as yet).

Comment: So if your record's data fields are private there's pretty much no way around this. You're going to need to use a "setter" procedure to initialize them, and you're just going to have to put up with this warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is what constructors are for, the following compiles with FPC *trunk* and produces no warnings:

```
{$mode delphi}

type TTest =
  record
    a,b: double;
    constructor Init(x,y: double);
  end;

constructor TTest.Init(x,y: double);
begin
  a := x;
  b := y;
end;


var t: TTest;
begin
  t.Init(0.1,0.2);
end.
```

Comment: Hi Marco. I'm using using FPC 2.06 (downloaded fpc-2.6.2.i386-win32.exe) and that definitely doesn't work for me. Like I said previously, I get the error: "**Error: Constructors aren't allowed in records or record helpers**", so it wont even compile. What is "FPC trunk", is that like the latest "overnight" build or something. If so then this feature will be in the next stable release, is that correct?

Comment: Also one other question. If this is going to part of the next stable release, is it true that the use of the keyword "constructor" rather than "procedure" here does not actually change the way it operates in any way? That is, so called "syntactic sugar". This seems to be story that I'm getting so far when I look into the difference between constructors and regular methods for records.

Comment: One last thing if anyone running a "trunk" build can answer. So "constructor" is now allowed and warning message suppressed. But just wondering, is warning message also suppressed even if you still use procedure instead of constructor? Just wondering, because Delphi (D2009) appears to not care either way.

Comment: 2.6.2 is the last stable from the stable branch (2.6). trunk is 2.7.x from the unstable (development) branch. Will probably become 2.8 in a fat year or so, but first there will be a 2.6.4 from stable. With procedure instead of constructor there is a warning. FPC is simply stricter with warnings and runtime checks. Delphi seems to have forgotten its roots in that respect.

Comment: Ok thanks Marco. I'm setting that as answered now, but I've got to admit that I still don't really like the idea of constructors for simple records like this. For one thing, I think a constructor should only be called once, whereas something that just sets values like my Init() could conceivably be called many times throughout a variables "lifetime".

Comment: I never really warmed to methods in records at all.